# How to check 'IN' clause in Druid Transformation Spec Expression

Tags: druid

I'm looking for checking 'IN' clause in Druid Transformation Expression.

I want to check and derive a field with the below condition :

```
severity_analysis_period IN ('Critical') 
  THEN '>4hr Deviation' ,
when severity_analysis_period IN ('High', 'Medium', 'Low') 
  THEN '<4hr Deviation' else 'No Deviation'.
```

I wrote the transformation spec like this , but it doesn't work :

```
    "transformSpec": {
      "transforms": [
        {
          "type": "expression",
          "name": "deviation",
          "expression": "if(\"severity_analysis_period\"='Critical'),'>4hr Deviation',if(\"severity_analysis_period\" in ('High','Medium','Low'),'<4hr Deviation','No Deviation'))"
        },
        {
          "type": "expression",
          "name": "deviation_day",
          "expression": "if((\"severity_day\"='Critical'),'>4hr Deviation',if(\"severity_day in\" ('High','Medium','Low'),'<4hr Deviation','No Deviation'))"
        },
        {
          "type": "expression",
          "name": "deviation_hour",
          "expression": "if((\"severity_day_hour\"='Critical'),'>4hr Deviation',if(\"severity_day_hour\" in ('High','Medium','Low'),'<4hr Deviation','No Deviation'))"
        }
      ],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a case statement:

```
{
      "type": "expression",
      "name": "deviation_hour",
      "expression": 'case_simple("severity_analysis_period", "Critical", ">4hr Deviation", "High", "<4hr Deviation", "Medium", "<4hr Deviation", "Low", "<4hr Deviation", "No Deviation")'
}
```

The `case_simple` function works like:

```
case_simple(expr, value1, result1, [[value2, result2, ...], else-result])
```

See also: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/misc/math-expr.html